# How do I tell VS.Net's autocomplete that I'm using HTML not XHTML?

Tags: visual-studio

In an HTML5 document (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), if I type `<br>` the Visual Studio.Net auto-completion stuff "helpfully" changes it to `<br />` when I type the closing `>`. I've looked in the options for the HTML designer, and don't see anything about changing that, nor do I see any options at the project level. Is there a way?

Granted, `<br />` is valid HTML5, but it's not what I want — and even if I change my doctype to HTML4 (where `<br />` *isn't* valid although browsers are smart about allowing it), the environment does the same thing. So I'm thinking it's not working from the doctype, but from some other setting I haven't found.

I'm using VS.Net 2008, some other team members are still back on VS.Net 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: You right-click the document and choose **Formatting and validation...** That takes you to the options under **Text Editor | HTML | Format** (you could also get their via Options, of course). There are some general options there, though nothing like simply choosing your target markup. But you can click a **Tag-specific options...** button to customize each tag individually. (In my case, it didn't even list the `br` tag but I was able to add it and tell it not to make it a self-closing tag.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative in VS 2010 (it may work in VS 2008 as well but I don't have it installed to see if the option is there).

T.J's solution works great, but I didn't want to go spend time adding a bunch of tags and making them not self-closing, so I looked around through the other settings and found an alternative.

Go to **Tools | Options | Text Editor | HTML | Formatting** and deselect the Auto insert close tag option. This worked great for me, because I hate that feature anyway. This won't be a very good solution for you if you like that feature :)